# Am I reading the HDHP rules correctly?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hdhp

I'm puzzled by [the rules for High Deductible Health Plans.](https://www.healthcare.gov/glossary/high-deductible-health-plan/)

> For 2019, the IRS defines a high deductible health plan as any plan with a deductible of **at least** $1,350 for an individual or $2,700 for a family.

That's understandable.  My in-network deductible for individuals is $1,500 and $3,000 for family, so the plan qualifies as HD.

> An HDHP’s total yearly out-of-pocket expenses (including deductibles, copayments, and coinsurance) **can’t be more than** $6,750 for an individual or $13,500 for a family.

This seems to imply that the OOP must be **less than** $6,750, and that seems completely bass-ackwards.

Thus, am I reading it wrong, or is the regulation completely bass-ackwards?

Comment: Yes HDHP has a 'maximum' out of pocket.